# How do I go about copying a row when I only have the row number to work with?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an ERP-system that stores all of my info in a spreadhseet, each row of data has its own ID number and I'm trying to write a code that pulls the entire row up when typing in the ID number for that specific row. Since the format for where it's going is not in a straight line I need to accsess each individual cell and copy it from that destination

I have already got the code for locating which row the data is on, now I trying to find a way to copy each cell I need from that row over to where I want it to go but I don't know how to use the row number any further.

```
InputValue = Application.InputBox("Type ID number", "Pull a delivery-note back up")


If InputValue = vbNullString Then

    MsgBox "Please type an ID number to proceed"

Else

    idRow = Sheets("Arkiv").Columns("A:A").Find(what:=InputValue).Row
    'To output current row (temporarily there) *IGNORE*
    MsgBox idRow


End If
```

Haven't found a way to further solve this

Comment: This is the address of the cell where the ID is `Sheets("Arkiv").Range("A" & idRow)`. To copy the data from say `Col F` in that row, the address of the cell will be `Sheets("Arkiv").Range("F" & idRow)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim InputValue As Variant
    Dim rID As Range

    InputValue = Application.InputBox("Type ID number", "Pull a delivery-note back up")


    If InputValue = vbNullString Then

        MsgBox "Please type an ID number to proceed"

    Else
        With Sheets("Arkiv")

            Set rID = .Columns("A:A").Find(what:=InputValue)

            'Check the ID was found.
            If Not rID Is Nothing Then
                Union(.Cells(rID.Row, 1), .Cells(rID.Row, 2), .Cells(rID.Row, 5)).Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
            Else

                MsgBox "ID not found."
            End If

        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

Note - this will copy to cells A1:C1.